# How do I click a button on an embedded web control from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, html

There is a page loaded in a webBrowser1 object. It has a "button" tag, which is the button that I need to click. It's basic button. No JavaScript, etc.

I tried:

1) to click it with "enter":

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")[0].Focus();
Sendkeys.Sendwait("{ENTER}");
```

That didn't work.

2) to call the "click" event:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

That also didn't work because it's not JavaScript.

3) the "click" handler:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")[0].Click +=
        new System.EventHandler(button_click1);
```

This also can not work, because from what I've read, this is an event handler which triggers after the user actually clicks on this button.

So I ran out of options. What else can I try?

Comment: I have used button.InvokeMember("click"); in previous projects and it worked fine. not sure why it's not working for you. Maybe this link will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654442/invokememberclick-webbrowser-help

Comment: Have you looked into using Selenium with .Net?  You could get some serious record/playback rapid development code generation if you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this for capturing the button event in web browser using c#

```
HtmlElement el = webBrowser1.Document.All["mybutton"];
object obj = el.DomElement;
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("click");
mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```

OR

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.wb.Url = new Uri("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?.intl=gr&.src=ym");
   this.wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
}
public void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement username = this.wb.Document.All["username"];
    username.SetAttribute("value", "kataras2012@yahoo.gr");
    HtmlElement pass = this.wb.Document.All["passwd"];
    pass.SetAttribute("value", "passTest");
    HtmlElement goButton = this.wb.Document.All[".save"];
    goButton.InvokeMember("click");

    return;
}
```

i hope it will helps you