# Modify Header for InvokeMember("click") of C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, browser

I want to change the normal header of a click request from the`InvokeMember("click")` method.
Tell me how?

Comment: Salam: see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2656794/1495442

Comment: @Ria Salam, I can use from `InvokeMember` method, but i want to change header of request that made by this raised click event.